# jQuery hide li after specific number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('li[data-number=4]').after().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-number="0">1</li>
    <li data-number="1">2</li>
    <li data-number="2">3</li>
    <li data-number="3">4</li>
    <li data-number="4">5</li>
    <li data-number="5">6</li>
    <li data-number="6">7</li>
    <li data-number="7">8</li>    
</ul>
```

I want to hide all element after data-number 4 and want to get first hidden li number. The output will 5. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: Check `nextAll()`. If you want to hide all elements after specific index see `:gt()` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.after()` means: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements. [API](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

What you want instead is `.nextAll()`: Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector. [API](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

So your code becomes:

```
$('li[data-number=4]').nextAll().hide();
```

To get the first hidden, use `$('li:hidden').first()`. Docs for `:hidden` and `.first()`: http://api.jquery.com/hide/, https://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('li:gt(4)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-number="0">1</li>
    <li data-number="1">2</li>
    <li data-number="2">3</li>
    <li data-number="3">4</li>
    <li data-number="4">5</li>
    <li data-number="5">6</li>
    <li data-number="6">7</li>
    <li data-number="7">8</li>    
</ul>
```

you can use just `$('li:gt(4)').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following js code to achieve your purpose in single line..!

Instead of using [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method you need to use [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method.

```js
var firstHidden = $('[data-number=4]').nextAll().hide().first();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-number="0">1</li>
    <li data-number="1">2</li>
    <li data-number="2">3</li>
    <li data-number="3">4</li>
    <li data-number="4">5</li>
    <li data-number="5">6</li>
    <li data-number="6">7</li>
    <li data-number="7">8</li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If its simple, why not use a loop?
Get a an each loop going through all list iteams  $(ul li).each();  then we can access the data- values

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```js
$('li[data-number=4]').nextAll().hide();
var firstHiddenLiNumber = $('li[data-number=4]').next().data('number');
console.log(firstHiddenLiNumber);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-number="0">1</li>
    <li data-number="1">2</li>
    <li data-number="2">3</li>
    <li data-number="3">4</li>
    <li data-number="4">5</li>
    <li data-number="5">6</li>
    <li data-number="6">7</li>
    <li data-number="7">8</li>    
</ul>
```